# How create CurrentIndexChanged signal for QAbstractListModel in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals, qabstractlistmodel

I have a class that inherited from QAbstractListModel. now i want to create a signal for this class Liken below

**BookListModel.h**

```
signals:
    void currentIndexChanged(int i);
```

now i have want to use this in below method

```
QVariant BookListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{

    int i=index.row();
    emit currentIndexChanged();
}
```

but got this error:

> error: C2662: 'void BookListModel::currentIndexChanged(int)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const BookListModel' to 'BookListModel &'

How can i create current index changed signal for this class?

Comment: use the `dataChanged` signal

Comment: What do you mean by *current index*?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o I want to use this for loading remind of list.I used this listmodel in GridView  and when user have scrolled to end i want to load for example another 10 book at the end of book

Comment: @mohsen you must consider that a model knows nothing about user selection, scrolling etc. It should be the view to track such actions.

Comment: Also: by *GridView* you mean `QTableView` or else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the `data` function is `const`.
Just declare your singal const as well and it should work:

```
signals:
    void currentIndexChanged(int i) const;
```

See this answer: [Is it possible to emit a Qt signal from a const method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781449/is-it-possible-to-emit-a-qt-signal-from-a-const-method?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

I would point out that a list model should not (and it does not) know nothing about user actions, which are handled by the view.

Suppose we have a very simple model like this:

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class Model : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QStringList list;

public:
    Model()
    {
        //adds 100 items
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            list << QString("ITEM #") + QString::number(i+1);
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        return list.size();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if(index.isValid() && (role == Qt::DisplayRole))
        {
            int row = index.row();
            if(row < list.size())
            {
                return list[row];
            }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

public slots:
    void scrolledToEnd()
    {
        //adds 10 more items
        int count = list.size();
        for(int i=count; i<(count + 10); i++)
            list << QString("ITEM #") + QString::number(i+1);

        emit layoutChanged();
    }
};
```

As you can see, I added a `scrolledToEnd` slot, to be called when the user scrolled the view to the end. Extra items are added to the model and the `layoutChanged` signal is emitted to update the view. The slot is supposed to be connected to a signal which is emitted by some object who is in control of the view vertical scroll bar.

So, let's lay out a `QTableView` in a `QMainWindow` ui, and give the window a slot and a signal like these:

```
public slots:
    void scrollValueChanged(int value);
signals:
    void scrolledToEnd();
```

In the window constructor, we set the view model to a new instance of our `Model` class:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

Model * model = new Model();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

then connect the `valueChanged` signal of the view's `verticalScrollBar` to the `scrollValueChanged` slot of the window:

```
connect(ui->tableView->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::scrollValueChanged);
```

and the `scrolledToEnd` signal of the window to the `scrolledToEnd` slot of the model:

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::scrolledToEnd, model, &Model::scrolledToEnd);
```

In the window slot implementation, if the scroll bar reached its maximum value, the `scrolledToEnd` signal is emitted:

```
void MainWindow::scrollValueChanged(int value)
{
    if(value==ui->tableView->verticalScrollBar()->maximum())
    {
        emit scrolledToEnd();
    }
}
```

The signal will be caught by the model slot, and a new set of ten items will be appended to the model.